# Testing haskell equality on Doubles with HUnit?

Tags: haskell

Does HUnit have some way of doing approximate equalities? Clearly, this fails:

```
test1 = TestCase (assertEqual "Should equal" (get_scores) [(0.3, 0.3), (0.6, 0.36), (1.0, 0.3399999)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I don't know if there's a correct/official/accepted way to do this.

---

[Here's](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.4.2/doc/html/src/Test-HUnit-Base.html#Test) the source code for `assertEqual`:

```
assertEqual :: (Eq a, Show a) => String -- ^ The message prefix 
                              -> a      -- ^ The expected value 
                              -> a      -- ^ The actual value
                              -> Assertion
assertEqual preface expected actual =
  unless (actual == expected) (assertFailure msg)
 where msg = (if null preface then "" else preface ++ "\n") ++
             "expected: " ++ show expected ++ "\n but got: " ++ show actual
```

Based on that and on [JUnit's function for testing double equality](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29), we could create our own in the same style:

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

assertEquals ::   String  -- ^ The message prefix
               -> Double  -- ^ The maximum difference between expected and actual
               -> Double  -- ^ The expected value
               -> Double  -- ^ The actual value
               -> Assertion
assertEquals preface delta expected actual = 
  unless (abs (expected - actual) < delta) (assertFailure msg)
 where msg = ... same as above ...
```

Comment: A fixed maximum delta is seldom a very useful way of checking almost-equality. The [ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754)-`AEq` class does this much more sophisticated.

Answer (score 4):

For floating point approximate comparison, there's a library with some nice utils:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754

Comment: That library doesn't work on Windows. It fails when I try to import `Data.AEq`.

Comment: Right. It imports libm for some floating ops. Should be easy to fix (by installing + pointing to a libm, for example) but I can't direct you to the exact right way.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was first asked, the [`HUnit-approx` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-approx) has been released.

It uses an implicit variable, `epsilon`, and an approximate equality operator, `~?~`, instead of `~=?`.

A short example:

```hs
tweak :: Float -> Float
tweak x = x * 1.0001

egApproxTest  = let ?epsilon = 0.01 in
    [ "strictEqual" ~: 0 ~=? tweak 0,
      "approxEqual" ~: 2 ~?~ tweak 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, this helper function worked well enough:

```
assertFloatEqual text a b = 
  assertEqual text (take 6 (show a)) (take 6 (show b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my data type an instance of equal with code there to use 2 decimal places. Here is an example using a cartesian point:

```
data Point =  Point { x_axis :: Double, y_axis :: Double, z_axis :: Double } 
              deriving (Show)
```

### Instance of equal

In order to avoid double rounding errors and  trig errors which cause
the same point, and thus CornerPoints, to be `/=` due to tiny differences,
give it a range of `.01`, and still allow the points to be equal.

```
axisEqual :: (Eq a, Num a, Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> Bool

axisEqual  a b
  | (abs (a - b)) <= 0.011 = True
  | otherwise      = False

instance Eq Point where

  Point x y z == Point xa ya za
    | (axisEqual x xa) && (axisEqual y ya)  &&(axisEqual z za) = True 
    | otherwise = False
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the `Eq` class this way. Really almost-equal is one issue (even that, one could argue shouldn't be done with `==`), but depending the context this `Point` type is used in, 0.01 may not even be small at all! If you're working on points only 0.001 away, _everything_ will compare equal!

Comment: In my case 0.011 milli-meters is more than enough resolution for a 3D printer. I could have easily made it 0.0000001 and it would have worked just as well in my code. As long as it gets rid of those tiny differences caused by using doubles. After all, how often does 1.0000000000e-17 make a difference. If it does, perhaps use something besides a double. Now I can use == within my program, as well as in my testing, with the exact same results.

Comment: Well, in the applications I'm working on, it does frequently make a difference. Get the electron mass wrong by 10⁻¹⁷ kg, and you're in for some trouble... which doesn't mean `Double` is not accurate enough BTW – that's the nice thing about floating-point: for such small quantities it automatically gets super-accurate, in a way you'd never need for bigger quantities. My point is that the uncertainty margin should be adapted to the actual values, to match the uncertainty produced in calculations.