# How do I compare Double values in Hunit?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hunit

I would like to understand how I can use HUnit to compare Real values, specifically Double. I say errors, as far as I understand HUnit has no standard methods for comparing this type, so I stumbled upon this question:

[Testing haskell equality on Doubles with HUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318146/testing-haskell-equality-on-doubles-with-hunit)

From it I learned that there is [Data.AEq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.8.0/docs/Data-AEq.html), which gives the right comparator `-==` (the right one as far as I understand it)

But the presence of the comparator does not tell me anything about how to compare with it in HUnit, for example there is such a test:

```
test1 :: Test
test1 = TestCase (assertEqual "Test linearApproximation" expectedResult (linearApproximation (1, 10) 0.95 points))
  where
    points = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
    expectedResult = Linear [Just 1.0,Just 1.95,Just 2.9,Just 3.8499999999999996,Just 4.8,Just 5.75,Just 6.699999999999999,Just 7.6499999999999995,Just 8.6,Just 9.549999999999999]
     [Just 2.0,Just 2.95,Just 3.9,Just 4.85,Just 5.8,Just 6.75,Just 7.699999999999999,Just 8.649999999999999,Just 9.6,Just 10.549999999999999]
```

I think it's clear to everyone why I don't like this test, I wish I hadn't written such an exact `expectedResult`, but I don't understand how I can apply `-==`

Maybe there is another way?

Comment: I don't know the full API, so I'm going to get this a little wrong, but the important idea should be there: generally, a call like `assertEqual a b` is implemented as a call like `assert (a == b)`, so just make your own call to `assert` that uses `~==` instead of `==`, as in `assert (a ~== b)`.

Comment: What I tend to do is to just define my own equality operator ad hoc in the test module. Dirty, but it has the advantage that you can tweak on the spot what epsilon you allow (and whether in an absolute or relative sense) – which, it turns out, is almost always necessary to customize, because different computations have different amounts of floating gunk in them. Check out also the `HUnit-approx` package, as [suggested by Adam Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70752097/745903) – looks like it offers similar flexibility but somewhat less ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I use. In the ***tests/*** folder I create this module:

```hs
module Approx where

-- round x to n digits
approx :: Int -> Double -> Double
approx n x = fromInteger (round $ x * (10^n)) / (10.0^^n)

-- check whether rounded x1 and rounded x2 are equal
approxEqual :: Int -> Double -> Double -> Bool
approxEqual n x1 x2 = approx n x1 == approx n x2
```

I could do instead, shorter: `abs (x1 - x2) < 10.0^^(-n)`, but I have this `approx` function for historical reasons.

Then in the `Main` module, I have for example:

```hs
module Main where
import           Approx
import           Math.NevilleTheta -- this is a module from my package
import           Test.Tasty       (defaultMain, testGroup)
import           Test.Tasty.HUnit (assertBool, testCase)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain $
  testGroup "Tests"
  [ testCase "a theta_c value" $ do
      let expected = 0.902705416117337 
          obtained = theta_c 1.0 2.5
      assertBool "" (approxEqual 10 expected obtained)

  ]
```

And in the **cabal** file:

```yaml
test-suite unit-tests
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:              Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:       tests/
  other-modules:        Approx
  Build-Depends:        base >= 4.7 && < 5
                      , tasty
                      , tasty-hunit
                      , jacobi-elliptic
  Default-Language:     Haskell2010
```

where `jacobi-elliptic` is my package.

Alternatively, you could do

```hs
assertEqual "" (approx 10 expected) (approx 10 obtained)
```

This has one advantage: if the equality does not hold, the two different values are printed with the failure notification.

---

## EDIT

I finally wrote a custom "assert" function.

```hs
module Approx where
import           Test.Tasty.HUnit (Assertion, assertEqual)

-- round x to n digits
approx :: Int -> Double -> Double
approx n x = fromInteger (round $ x * (10^n)) / (10.0^^n)

-- assert approximate equality
assertApproxEqual :: String -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Assertion
assertApproxEqual prefix n x1 x2 = 
  assertEqual prefix (approx n x1) (approx n x2)
```

This stuff can be generalized to `Num a` instead of `Double`.